# Анимация "волна" при нажатии на TextView

Tags: android, анимация

Есть TextView `id=b7`

[image: TextView с id=7]

Мне нужен эффект анимации такой же, как и при нажатии кнопки Android > 5.0, то есть такая волна, идущая от места нажатия. Как реализовать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Прошу, называется `Ripple Effect`

[Тут код для установки и инструкция](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect)

Comment: ну как это то ???

Comment: Да, спасибо, именно оно, наконец-то я установлю красивую анимацию) А то даже не знал как называется